# How do I convert a char into int in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have created an Array of type char.
In that Array, I am accepting integers.
Like 0, 1 or anything for that matter.
The question asks for summation of values stored into the Array. But since I have declared the array as char type, so 0 would be accepted like '0'. SO, How should I convert '0' to 0.
Also, Can characters greater than 10(ten) also be converted into integers ?

The input is a string of integers; like 00012312.
Also is there a better method of inputting these numbers apart from this generic character Array method.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: there is no magic going on for `char`. '0' is just another way to write 48. we probably need to see some code to be able to help you

Comment: Given the input "string of integers" "00012312", do you want to convert this to a single integer 12312, or to a sequence of eight integers, namely [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]?  Also, is the input string in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii), so that the ASCII character '7' is represented by decimal 55 (as an example)?

Comment: In my program, I have to convert to a sequence of integers ,like [0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2]. But, If you also tell me about how to convert 12312 into int, that would be totally great.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: while I am sure that indeed this is a duplicate and has been asked a lot of times before, I don't know if that is really a good duplicate to close it as...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a character array like this

```
char a[] = "00012312";
```

then you can find the sum the following way

```
int sum = 0;

for ( char *p = a; *p; ++p ) sum += *p - '0';
```

If you need to convert the content of the array to an integer then you can write

```
int x = ( int )std::strtol( a );
```

It is the same as

```
int x = std::atoi( a );
```

Answer (score 1):

A char containing 0...9 can be converted to an int by subtracting '0'.  Study an ASCII chart to understand why.

```
char c = '7';
int n = c - '0';
```

Comment: Totally works.. Thanks. But how can I convert two digit integers into int. Like 15 for example.

Comment: @user3803501 15 consists from two characters. So it is totally unclear what you are speaking about because an object of type character can contain only one character.